# Vuejs:Why is render method returning dynamic `<component>` giving errors?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to return vue's builtin `<component/>` from the `render` method, but it is not recognizing the component. what could be the possible mistake?

```js
Vue.component('comp1',{
  template:'<h1>Component1</h1>'
});
Vue.component('comp2',{
  template:'<h1>Component2</h1>'
});
let app=new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:function(){
    return {
      comp:'comp1'
    }
  },
  mounted:function(){
    setInterval(()=>{
      if(this.comp=='comp1'){
        this.comp="comp2"
      }else{
        this.comp="comp1"
      }
    },1000);
  },
  render (h) {
    return h('component', this.comp)
  }
})
```

[image: Link to image]

linkto js bin: https://jsbin.com/wakivet/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: It looks like you just want `h(this.comp)`, no need for the `'component'` part.

Comment: @skirtle  I want the component to be rendered somewhere in a nested array. All the custom components are recognized by render method and I am wondering why render(h){ return h('component',this.comp); } is not being recognized by Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
render(h){
     return h('component',this.comp);
   }
```

with

```
  template: '<component :is="comp" />'
```

Comment: yes that works, but the template is more complex and I want the `component` to be rendered somewhere in a nested array. All the custom components are recognized by `render` method and I am wondering why
 `render(h){
     return h('component',this.comp);
   }`
is not being recognized by Vue..

Comment: I suppose this is a limitation of createElement function that it requires a real element.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in component called `component` in Vue.

Vue needed a syntax for creating dynamic components in a template. It also needed a way to solve the problems caused by in-DOM templates requiring specific elements as children of other elements. Both of these problems could be solved the same way, with the introduction of the `is` attribute.

But even though the desired tag name is specified via the `is` attribute we still need to include a tag name in the template. Any tag will work, but the convention is to use the tag `<component>`.

```html
<component :is="comp">
```

Using this convention allows other developers to know that the tag is dynamic. It also makes it easier for the Vue template compiler to optimise the template.

Vue will log a warning if anyone tries to register a global component called `component`, just like it would for other reserved tag names. This helps to ensure there's no ambiguity when those tags are used.

However, it is just a convention. Using other tags will work just fine and with in-DOM templates it is sometimes necessary, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats.

But what about `render` functions?

The first argument passed to the function `h` is the tag name. We don't need to use tricks like the `is` attribute to make that dynamic, we can just pass it directly:

```js
h(this.comp)
```

In fact, if you write a template containing `<component :is="comp">` then Vue will compile it down to something very similar to this. The compiled `render` function doesn't keep the `is` attribute, it throws that away and just passes its value to the `h` function.

You can see this for yourself if you inspect a compiled template. For example, you can use the tool at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation to see how templates are compiled to `render` functions. The function `_c` is what you called `h`.

So to reiterate, there is no such component as `<component>`. It is merely a placeholder in template syntax for some other component. When you're in a `render` function you should just use the desired component directly.